# How to pass httpclienthandler to httpclientfactory explicitly?

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclientfactory

I thought of using HttpClientFactory but I need to attach the certificate while making a call Currently, I am using HttpClient, But don't know how to attach the certificate.
**Below is the httpClient code:**

```
HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls12,
    ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual
};
httpClientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(CertHelper.GetCertFromStoreByThumbPrint(_Settings.MtlsThumbPrint, StoreName.My, _Settings.IgnoreCertValidChecking));

httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = OnServerCertificateValidation;

HttpClient _client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler)
{
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
    BaseAddress = new Uri(_Settings.BaseUrl)
};
```

So, how to convert the above httpClient to HttpClientFactory?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you mean by using `ServiceCollection`, You can configure the handler when setting up the client

```
services.AddHttpClient("MyClient", client => {
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_Settings.BaseUrl)
})
.ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => {
    var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls12,
        ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual
    };
    httpClientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(CertHelper.GetCertFromStoreByThumbPrint(_Settings.MtlsThumbPrint, StoreName.My, _Settings.IgnoreCertValidChecking));

    httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = OnServerCertificateValidation;

    return httpClientHandler;
});
```

That way when `IHttpClientFactory` is injected and the client is called.

```
var _client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("MyClient");
```

the created client will have the desired certificates already configured.

Comment: Hi @Nkosi, Thanks for your answer, But my question is about adding the certificate explicitly. But your code seems to add in the startup. But I need to add during Post request only

Comment: @BVWinoya `But I need to add during Post request only`. That cannot be done using factory.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this working for me. Certificate credentials taken from appsettings.json

```
var certPath = builder.Configuration["CertPath"];
var certKey = builder.Configuration["CertificateKey"];
var targetUrl = builder.Configuration["TargetUrl"];
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("MyClient", client => {
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(targetUrl);
})
.ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => {
    var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls13,
    };
    httpClientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(certPath, certKey));
        
    return httpClientHandler;
});
```